# Three js window resizing issue ( not real view size )

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm using Three js and I have an issue on mobile envirionment.

I used meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=no; initial-scale:1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" >
```

and initializing Threejs's canvas with following code.

```
function init(){
  container = document.createElement( 'div' );
  container.setAttribute('class', 'canvas');
  container.style.width = preMetaWidth;
  container.style.height = preMetaHeight;
...
}
```

The problem is, when I run the web on mobile, it's size is fine when I just run.

However, when I called some Three.js event, like raycaster to click 3D object, the `<body>` size is changing as not I coded.

I never set changing it's size, but when resizing window.

```
...
function onWindowResize(){
  if(deviceInfo == 0)
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  else
      renderer.setSize( preMetaWidth, preMetaHeight );
  ...
}
```

As I checked with chrome debugger, When I run the web, the size is fine.

But after I call some events like ray-caster to click 3D object,

The whole HTML is being resized.

I want it to let has device's real view size, but it doesn't work.

So I tried to let it has real size with:

```
const preMetaWidth: window.innerWidth;
const preMetaHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

and using it on `function init()` and `function onWindowResize()`, but also doesn't work.

How can I let it has device's real size for whole running time?

I don't want it to change it's size at it's will.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by **device's real size**? Do you mean the viewport size or the device actual pixel size? See the difference [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/target/using/experiences/vec/mobile-viewports.html)

Comment: @a.barbieri I mean, my phone's screen size is 980 x 1081 (pixels), and I want to show as the pixels. But after the event, web's size is changing into 412 x 773 (px).

Comment: @a.barbieri Oh Thanks! I think this is the reason of changing size.

Comment: I'd suggest you refer to the viewport size rather than the device real size. Developers rarely use real device size, so if it's not needed I would avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: The default [ThreeJS example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) is always a good reference/starting point. The code is [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html)